When .NET Core uses httpclient to implement HTTP requests, it crashes after receiving over 20 requests. May I ask how to optimize?
I'm using HttpClient to implement HTTP requests in .NET Core. As shown in the following code, using dependency injection, the program crashes once 20 or 50 requests are made simultaneously.
MyHttpService:
namespace WebApplication1.UComon
{
    public class MyHttpService
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

        public MyHttpService(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            _httpClient = httpClient;
        }

        public async Task<string> GetExternalData(string url)
        {
            var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}

TestController:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using WebApplication1.UComon;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly MyHttpService _httpService;

        public TestController(MyHttpService httpService)
        {
            _httpService = httpService;
        }

        #region 测试httpclient
        [HttpGet, Route("PostHttp")]
        public IActionResult PostHttp()
        {
            string responseBody = "";
            //var service = new HttpService();
            //string getResponse = service.GetAsync("https://www.baidu.com/").Result;
            responseBody = _httpService.GetExternalData("https://www.baidu.com/").Result;
            return Ok(responseBody);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}

Using the JMeter tool for stress testing, it was found that crashes occur with a concurrency of 50.
The actual exception is :

System.AggregateException HResult=0x80131500 Message=One or more errors occurred. (An error occurred while sending the request.) Source=System.Private.CoreLib StackTrace: 在 System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) 在 System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result() 内部异常 1: HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. 内部异常 2: IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: 远程主机强迫关闭了一个现有的连接。. 内部异常 3: SocketException: 远程主机强迫关闭了一个现有的连接。

The translation of the Chinese message is :

The remote host forcibly closed an existing connection


You said "as shown in the following code", but there's nothing here that shows an error.  Where does it crash?  What is the error?

System.AggregateException
HResult=0x80131500
Message=One or more errors occurred. (An error occurred while sending the request.)
Source=System.Private.CoreLib
StackTrace:
在 System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
在 System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
内部异常 1:
HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
内部异常 2:
IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: 远程主机强迫关闭了一个现有的连接。.
内部异常 3:
SocketException: 远程主机强迫关闭了一个现有的连接。

For an async method call, don't use .Result but await that call. You will need to add the async keyword to the method signature: public async Task<IActionResult> PostHttp()

Even with tasks and stress testing tools, the concurrency is still around 20, which cannot be improved

Using await and Task is required, but might not be the reason based on your test result. And my assumption is that the issue is caused by exhausting the number of sockets. See this section, and the SocketException is aslo metioned in this section.

Therefore, could you pls try IHttpClientFactory instead of HttpClient and have a test again? Because IHttpClientFactory will help manage the connections which might be helpful for your scenario.. I don't have the environment for stress testing, could you pls share the test result?

The stress test results conducted using IhttpClientFactory are basically consistent with the current results

Translating the chinese error message results in: The remote host forcibly closed an existing connection
Consider that the server doesn't want you stress testing on their website and is closing the connection.

@codesix you haven't posted anything that shows an HttpClient problem yet. You posted something that says the remote service either you or crashed. I'd bet Baidu doesn't like people hammering it, no more than Google or StackOverflow does. If you keep this up your IP itself may get blacklisted\

@codesix the code has other issues though. For starters, that .Result is a bug. It just forces your controller to spinwait while waiting for a response. Make the action asynchronous and properly await the call. Second, the code never checks response for possible throttling information. You may be getting a 429 - Too many requests response whose Retry-After header specifies the duration of throttling. Previous responses probably contained rate limit headers too, specifying how many request are allowed/left

@codesix you could add rate limiting to prevent badly behaved clients too, by using the Rate Limiting Middleware. This way a bad client wouldn't cause your services to be throttled by the actual remote service

In my humble opinion, we can firstly to inject IHttpClientFactory instead of HttpClient, because although this HttpClient class implements IDisposable, declaring and instantiating it within a using statement is not preferred because when the HttpClient object gets disposed of, the underlying socket is not immediately released, which can lead to a socket exhaustion problem. While IHttpClientFactory has benefits that it manages the lifetime of HttpMessageHandler to avoid the mentioned problems/issues that can occur when managing HttpClient lifetimes yourself. We can see more details in this section.
By the way, we can see that Microsoft also recommend using IHttpClientFactory when we try to send http request. Just like what we discussed in the comment, if you already followed the document to inject IHttpClientFactory and create http client to send http request, I'm afraid we can check whether we add limitations for allowed concurrent requests. This depends on the web server you used. For example, if you host your web api in IIS, we might check requestLimit and requestQueueLimit in web.config file, you can take a look at this case and this document.
In the meantime, we also need to check the CPU usage and Memory usage when you execute stress test in your client. If it already went to 100% usage, you shall get SocketException too.

This answer is wrong and doesn't answer the question anyway. MyService is a Typed client. If it's registered with builder.Services.AddHttpClient<MyService> then HttpClientFactory is already used.

Our dear OP doesn't mentioned it anyway, but I just want OP to make sure he has builder.Services.AddHttpClient(); in Program.cs and inject IHttpClientFactory into his MyHttpService and use it tosend http request. Why you raise up a statement similar to if OP used xx then it already used HttpClientFactory so my post is wrong? May I get more description from you? I might misunderstand your point.

The answer is wrong because a) it doesn't answer the question and b) it makes the incorrect assumption that HttpClient is injected as-is. At best, this will cause additional delays not just to the poster but everyone else that sees this and assumes it answers their question

The translated error message says the remote service terminated the connection  - the app got throttled

The exception shared by OP is SocketException: the remote service terminated the one of the current connection, and OP described that he was doing a stess test and the exception occurred when the program crashes once 20 or 50 requests are made simultaneously. Based on this, I deduce it's due to socket exhaustion based on the Microsoft document I found and it indicate we should use IHttpClientFactory instead of HttpClient. Then I also think the issue might result from test machine performance or web server limiation. I shared my action plan in a post and ask OP to check.

I don't think it's wrong or might cause additional delays for OP or others have similar issue in future based on your description. Your statement is, if OP already registered with builder.Services.AddHttpClient<MyService>, then it already used HttpClientFactory. Then based on this assumption, at most you can say IHttpClientFactory doesn't make sense for resolving the issue. But I do find Microsoft document to say it could resolve socket exhaustion brough by HttpClient. You should point out that document is wrong or I misunderstood the document, and my other actions are wrong too.
